# Angular2 getting records with specific key: value

Tags: typescript

Whats the easiest way to get all the records from array with specific key: value pair?
The schema of the array is something like this:

```
Id
Priority
State
Title
Type
```

How to get all the records with Priority = 5 for example?

Comment: " all the records with Priority = 5" What are "all the records" ? is this an array of array ?

Comment: just a normal array of the schema as above

Answer (score 0):

try this method

```
<p *ngFor="let key of keysGetter(items)">{{key + ' : ' + items[key]}}</p>

keysGetter = Object.keys;
```

<kbd>[Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/HKeVKgH3Hi8MYbcdin80?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: I wanted something like find method. `result = data.find(x = > x.Priority === 5)` something like this